# Annoying white line between bootstrap panel header and body

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap 3 and collapsible panel. How to remove the white line between the header and the body when body is displayed.

HTML

```
<div class="panel-group">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTools" >Tools</a>                                    
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTools" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        hello
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.panel {
  background: #222222;
  border: 0;
}

.panel-default >.panel-heading {
  background: #222222;
  color: #eeeeee;
}

.panel-default >.panel-collapse {
  background: rgb(0, 145, 210);
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/magauthier/e3gmzdf8/)

Comment: `.panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse .panel-body {
    border-top: 0;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `panel-body` class has a `border-top: 1px #ddd` set.

You can set the color to `transparent` if you still want that 1px worth of space

Or you can set `border: 0` to get rid of it.

Comment: I put .panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse .panel-body { border-top: 0; } like mentioned by UncaughtTypeError in comment. Works now.